# Super Search Forward Slash in Search Bug

Tags: solspace, supersearch

Super Search 2.2.3
ExpressionEngine 2.10.1

I'm running into with Super Search where a search string containing '24/7' throws an error that appears to be related to the relevancy portion of the module code.  Googling has shown a (very) old changelog item related to forward slashes in search code, but nothing recent and nothing that appears to be the same as my problem.  Here's the error I end up with -

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '7'

Filename: super_search/mod.super_search.php

Line Number: 8825
```

It looks like the slash is breaking something in the code, and since the 7 is the next character that's what's showing up in the error.

Here's the results loop that's leading to the error -

```
{exp:super_search:results
    channel="channelname"
    status="statusname"
    relevance="channel-title=5+channel-type=5+channel-keywords=3+channel-description=2+channel-user-review=1"
    redirect_post="no"
    category_indicator="category_id"}
```

Has anyone else run into this problem?  It feels just edge-case-y enough to have slipped through without someone else seeing it, a combination of searching for a slash and using the relevance parameter.  Or I could be missing something simple.

Comment: Is the slash in the URL? Are you submitting **24/7** as a search term, or are you directly adding this to a URL? Submitting "24/7" from a form should convert it to `24SLASH7` in the URL. Are you seeing that?

Comment: @Solspace It's using Post rather than Get, so not in the URL.  But the post data looks like this - keywords=24%2F7&category-display=los+angeles&XID= (with the XID here).

Comment: Using `redirect_post="no"` then? Is the search form submitted through AJAX? If using AJAX, have you tried search & replacing `%2F` with `SLASH` before triggering the call?

Comment: I'm seeing a similar error… (EE v2.11.3 + super search 2.2.4) When trying to search for a string that contains: 'All Africa Ob/Gyn Meeting', the url does convert to `keywords=All+Africa+ObSLASHGyn+Meeting&x=0&y=0/` but I get no results… But if I change the search to "All Africa Ob Gyn Meeting" (without the slash) then I get 6 results, including one entry entitled "All Africa Ob/Gyn Meeting"… 